# Can no longer access SMB shares to a Windows server after 2016 upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, windows-server-2016, cifs, share

I've got a file server which hosts a load of SMB shares.

The users in this domain have mapped drives to the shares and use them on a daily basis.

I upgraded the OS on the Fileserver from 2012 R2 to 2016 a couple of weeks ago as I could not do a clean install on this one... I have just now discovered that I cannot access these file shares when connecting over the VPN or externally.

I can still ping the fileserver from over the vpn, both using its hostname and its IP... but no matter what I do I just can't see the shares.

If I try to browse to its hostname through file explorer, ie \FILESERVER1\  I get 'Windows cannot access \FILESERVER1'.

If I try to browse to its IP through file explorer, ie \172.16.1.10\, I get 'Windows cannot access \172.16.1.10\'.

This definitely worked before, and if I try to browse to a share on another machine within the same domain environment, it works fine. I see the shares and everything is fine.

I do not know if the upgrade to 2016 has applied to strange security setting, but a couple of the other machines in the environment are 2016 and I can browse to them with no issue, so I'm really scratching my head now.

**TL;DR....**

Can ping fileserver.

Can NOT browse to fileserver via the VPN or externally.

Can browse to fileserver from another machine within the same domain.

Can browse to other servers via the VPN and externally.

File server is the only one which I upgraded from 2012 R2 to 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your upgraded file server now only allows SMB2 or greater, and your other 2016 server is explicitly configured to allow SMB1. For some reason, your clients are not capable of using SMB2. This is bad.

In September 2016, security bulletin [MS16-114](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177186/ms16-114-description-of-the-security-update-for-windows-smbv1-server-s) was released. It described a fatal security flaw in SMB1.

As a result, SMB1 is now deprecated and on its way out. You should see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/ and the resources mentioned in it, and try to remove any dependencies to SMB1 if at all possible.